# Find whether input string is a valid English Word in C#

Tags: c#

Find whether the input string can form a valid English word. Ideally, we need to compare the input string in the English dictionary. Though an API dictionary is not required to search for the word, I have taken a hardcoded string array(which acts as an English dictionary here). Below is the code. Could you please help me with what's wrong with the code?
The output of the program should be the string of the dictionary if it matches the input string.

````
public class Program 

{
     public static string Jumble(string input)
     {
            string[] array = { "abstract", "car", "flight" };

            Dictionary<char, int> inputDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (inputDict.ContainsKey(input[i]))
                {
                    inputDict[input[i]]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    inputDict.Add(input[i], 1);
                }
            }

            Dictionary<char, int> arrayDict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < array[j].Length; k++)
                {
                    if (arrayDict.ContainsKey(array[j][k]))
                    {
                        arrayDict[array[j][k]]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrayDict.Add(array[j][k], 1);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < array[j].Length; k++)
                {
                    if(inputDict.ContainsKey(array[j][k]) && inputDict.ContainsValue(arrayDict[array[j][k]]) && array[j].Length == input.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(array[j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Doesn't match");
                    }
                }
            }

            return "";
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "tracabst";

            Console.WriteLine(Jumble(input));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
} ```
````

Comment: Why don't you just check `array.ToList().Contains(input)`?

Comment: The characters in `aracabst` can never be an anagram of `abstract` - too many `a`s

Comment: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @Luuk expected output, in this case, would be "abstract" which matches with the hardcoded string array's first element.

Comment: @KlausGütter Let me try that.

Comment: But I do not see the word `"tracabst"` in your array......?   The description of this question must be wrong?!

Comment: So you actually want to check, if any anagram of your input is contained in your dictionary? Instead of checking every possible anagram, I'd suggest to sort the characters in each word, and do the same for the input.  Ie in your static dictionary of allowed words you store `{"aabcrstt": "abstract"}` and if someone inputs "abstract" or "ttsrcbaa", both can easily be transformed to "aabcrstt" and then searched in the dictionary.

Comment: @Luuk Please see the description again, I have modified it.

Comment: Use `HashSet` class, it also allows to check if something is contained in it with `.Contains(word)`, but it will be faster A LOT

Comment: So what happens if someone enters "estw"? There are two matching words ("west" and "stew") in the english langugae ...

Comment: @derpirscher for this scenario the string search will happen in the hardcoded dictionary. And it should return "abstract". Ideally, it should return a list of words. But, as this question was asked in an interview. I was stuck while checking the conditions in the if block.

Comment: @KlausGütter I converted the input string to List<char> and tried checking if it contains array[j][k]. then kept removing it from the list. Finally checked if the list count has any items. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Program
{
    // Jumble: "tracabst";
    // Dictionary: "abstract", "car", "flight"
    public static string Jumble(string input)
    {
        string[] array = { "abstract", "car", "flight" };
        string result = "";

        List<char> listOfChar = new List<char>(input);

        for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < array[j].Length; k++)
            {
                if (listOfChar.Contains(array[j][k]) && array[j].Length == input.Length)
                {
                    listOfChar.Remove(array[j][k]);
                    result = array[j];
                }
            }
        }
        if(listOfChar.Count > 0)
        {
            return "Doesn't Match";
        }

        return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "tracabst";

        Console.WriteLine(Jumble(input));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This perfectly works fine.

However, it provides the solution in O(n^2).

Can you try for a better time complexity?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).